# HDD Physical Serial Number change

Tags: hard-drive

Well, the thing is:

I have a dead hard drive. The information inside isn't very important. BUT, I work with a licenced software. The licence XML executes a reading of some parameters of the computer, including the physical serial number of the HDD.

My question is: If I remove the pcb from the dead HDD, and put it into a new one (with the same characteristics of the dead one: brand, model, # of heads, firmware) would i get the serial number that i need back again?

Thanx for replying, and excuse me for my poor english.

Comment: Why not call the manufacturer of that software. Tell them that the harddisk is that and that they need to change the license. (You are already paying them for that license, and this can not be the first time this happens).

Comment: You assume the PCB board still works.  Why would you destroy the damaged hdd and a brand new hdd to only MAYBE have a chance of it working.  Seems like you should simply request the license be UPDATED.

Comment: At your own risk, give this a shot (Disclaimer: I haven't tried any of these utilities and cannot vouch for their safety or effectiveness): http://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-or-spoofing-hard-disk-hardware-serial-number-and-volume-id/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend replacing drive controllers or PCB's unless you know exactly what you are doing.  It won't really harm anything to try this but it won't help most times either, that stuff gets really complicated really quickly.

You mention the drive as dead, does that mean it won't power or spin or be seen in the BIOS?  Or is it there, it just doesn't work?

I would see if you can clone the bad drive to a known good drive that is at least the same size or larger than the original with dd_rescue.  This tools copies a drive bit for bit to a new drive, skipping bed sectors it encounters which will give you essentially an identitcal copy of the original drive, barring the bad the sectors it skipped.

[Here](http://thepracticalsysadmin.com/how-to-rescue-your-data-on-a-failing-hard-drive-with-dd_rescue/) is a blog post that shows you how to do this.